# How to Fade In Fade Out text during a loading with Animator?

Tags: android, animation, loading, animator

I want fade in and fade out some text during a loading in my app.
For begin i tried this in a loop with counter but it doesn't work.
I tried this :

```
        int i = 0;
        for(i=0; i < 5; i++){
            batteryAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(tvBattery, "alpha", 1).setDuration(600);
            batteryAnimator.setStartDelay(200);
            batteryAnimator.start();
            screenAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(tvScreen, "alpha", 1).setDuration(600);
            screenAnimator.setStartDelay(1500);
            screenAnimator.start();
            sensorAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(tvSensor, "alpha", 1).setDuration(600);
            sensorAnimator.setStartDelay(3000);
            sensorAnimator.start();
            wifiAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(tvWifi, "alpha", 1).setDuration(600);
            wifiAnimator.setStartDelay(4500);
            wifiAnimator.start();


            batteryAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(tvBattery, "alpha", 0).setDuration(600);
            batteryAnimator.setStartDelay(6000);
            batteryAnimator.start();
            screenAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(tvScreen, "alpha", 0).setDuration(600);
            screenAnimator.setStartDelay(6000);
            screenAnimator.start();
            sensorAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(tvSensor, "alpha", 0).setDuration(600);
            sensorAnimator.setStartDelay(6000);
            sensorAnimator.start();
            wifiAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(tvWifi, "alpha", 0).setDuration(600);
            wifiAnimator.setStartDelay(6000);
            wifiAnimator.start();
    }
```

I tried to use batteryAnimator.setRepeatedMode(ValueAnimator.RESTART) and battery.Animator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE), i think i have to use a thing like this but the texts flash like a christmas tree..

If someone can help me..

Comment: You need to add delay between your loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create this method. This will make your view (in your case, your `TextView`) fade in and out:

```
    public void fadeInAndOut(final View view) {
        ObjectAnimator fadeOut = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "alpha", 0f);
        fadeOut.setDuration(500);
        fadeOut.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());

        ObjectAnimator fadeIn = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "alpha", 1f);
        fadeIn.setDuration(500);
        fadeIn.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());

        AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
        set.play(fadeIn).after(fadeOut);

        set.start();
    }
```

Then, you need need call this function between some intervals. As an example, I am using `CountDownTimer`. It will be called 20 times with 1 second intervals.

```
new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
      //This will be called every time timer ticks
      fadeInAndOut(/*your TextView goes here*/)
    }

    public void onFinish() {
       //Timer is done. 
    }

}.start();
```

Comment: Thanks @Azizjon it works for once, but not in a loop.. I've create 4 timer.schedule so 4 Timer Task, for each TextView. Each TimerTask has one specific delay and one specific period. But if I put the code in a loop, it doesn't work, how i can add the code in my loop? I think the problem is the period or the delay . I have an other question, can I put every TimerTask in one for determinate a global period?

Comment: @zefz I have updated my answer. Can you check it once again?

Comment: it work, i understand why it was not the case before! I created a TimerTask with delay and period parameters, this TimerTask contains any TimerTask as i need (4 in my case) for execute text animation, tv after tv with a specific delay for each, and i stop the animation with timer.cancel() when the condition is ok! Thanks so much ! (y)

Comment: @zefz Glad to help. If my answer helped, accept the answer and upovote it so that it can help others as well. Cheers!

Comment: I'm a new web developer and new on stackoverflow too, i haven't reputation enough for upvote but I accepted the answer, thanks again! :)